# Multiply list of arrays by list of scalars and sum elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of arrays (factors) that I want to first multiply by a list of scalars (weights) and then sum the elements of the product of each array. I have tried the following but I get an error. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
factors = np.array([[f1], [f2], [f3]])
weights = np.array([0.333, 0.333, 0.333])
prod = np.sum(factors.transpose()*weights)
```

Comment: `factors` is not a list of arrays. It is an array.  Can you please provide a [mcve]? Inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: We could give an answer, but we prefer to see your error first.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following inputs

```
factors = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
weights = np.array([[2, 1, 0]]) # notice how this is a 2d array
```

First convert `weights` into a 2D "Vector" so that you can multiply each term

```
weights = weights.T # [[2], [1], [0]]
```

Then you can just simply multiply by using the `__mul__` dunder

```
new_factors = weights * factors # [[2, 4],[3, 4],[0, 0]]
```

Then you can just use `np.array.sum` to sum each row

```
new_factors.sum(axis=1)
```

The output is

```
array([6, 7, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Much appreciate it!